# Update several rows simultaneously SQL server

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, sql-update, spatial, geography

I'm in the process of creating a table that lists cities, state, zip, and long/lat. I've created another column (called GeoLoc) in my table that uses the geography data type. I would like to combine my latitude and longitude columns into the GeoLoc column so I can create SSRS map reports.

I can simply use an update statement to do this. For example:

```
UPDATE us_loc_data SET GeoLocation = 'POINT(-71.013202  43.005895)' WHERE Zip = '210'
```

The problem is, I have over 40,000 rows all having varying coordinates. Can I somehow perform this update on every row, simultaneously?

Comment: There are a couple ways you could do this.  Probably the easiest way is to make a temp table containing all of your changes, and doing an `UPDATE` that `JOIN`s to that table.

Comment: Post valid update query. `Point` requires `spatial reference ID` parameter. Also Point canno be used just like scalar function it should be used like `geography::Point(Lat, long,SRID)`

Comment: I guess I don't understand how my update is invalid. Is this tutorial just incorrect? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2552/creating-an-ssrs-map-report-with-data-pinpoints/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Update us_loc_data SET GeoLocation = geography::Point(B.lat,b.Lng,4326 )
 From  us_loc_data A
 Join  YourLatLngTable B on (A.Zip=B.Zip)
```

Comment: I'll try this real quick and get back to you.

Comment: @AnthonySims Happy it helped